# Creating an API with flash that dosen't care about any input parameters

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to create an api with Flask that just returns a json, regardless of input params, the method should be get tho.
I want this because the api will be called with multiple headers but none interest me, i just want to return a certain json.

Comment: can you explain a bit clearly.

Comment: You should include what you have done so far. Some code. Anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you mean something like the following:

```
from flask import jsonify 

@app.route('/send', methods=['GET'])
def returns_json():
    data = {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Linus',
        'admin': True
    }
    return jsonify(data)
```

The above endpoint only accepts GET methods and you could use Flask's jsonify method to serialize simple data types. If you have more complex data types, you might need to use something like marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your json and return it using the jsonify() function.

```
@app.route('/api')
def my_api():

    # json_response can either be a list or dictionary

    return jsonify(json_response)
```